# Add view to XML layout programmatically and make its z order below an existing view

Tags: android

I have an XML layout with some custom tabs, a heading, and a `ProgressBar`(`main.xml`).  I wish to add another XML layout(`home.xml`) to the `main.xml` layout, as i wish to keep `main.xml` re-usable for other activity's layouts and simply add things to it as necessary.

`home.xml` contains a `ScrollView` and a `TextView`.  I am currently using my Activity's `LayoutInflator` to add `home.xml` to `main.xml`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, rootLayout);
```

`rootLayout` is the root layout of `main.xml` and is a `RelativeLayout`

The problem: after inflating `R.layout.home` into `rootLayout`, it seems as though the `ProgressBar` contained in `rootLayout` is hidden underneath the content of `home.xml`

Is there a way to tell certain views(via XML) to float above other views when the layout is constructed in this way?

if not, am i forced to use methods such as `progressBar.bringToFront()` to raise targeted views to the top?

what alternatives do i have in z-ordering views when some layouts are constructed using inflation?

edit: it seems as though the `bringToFront()` method is not doing what i expect - i call it on one of my `Button` views and it still appears to be ordered below all other views(which were inflated) and remains unclickable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using `ViewStub` instead of manually adding it and set the set the `inflateId` with `setInflateId(R.layout.home)`

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html

Edit: 
Google seem have to moved the android developer from their android page to blogspot.

Updated Link:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html

Comment: this worked PERFECTLY!! thanks! my first time using a `ViewStub`, now i can see what they're good for

Answer (score 5):

Views are drawn based on their order in the parent. For instance, the child at index 0 is always (at least with the current layouts, except Gallery) drawn first and the child at index count - 1 is always drawn last. bringToFront() simply moves a View from its current position in the parent to the last. Note that changing the index of a child can affect its position on screen (for instance in a horizontal LinearLayout, moving a child from index 0 to index count - 1 will also move it from the far left to the far right.)